# Error in swapping characters in stringbuffer object

Tags: java, stringbuffer

i am trying to sort a string in the alphabetical order, however i am facing an error  in the line :

```
 sb.charAt(j)=sb.charAt(j+1);
```

where the compiler shows an error as `expected variable; found value`

the rest of the code is as follows :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class a
{
 public static void main(String[] agrs)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = sc.next();
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append(s);
    for(int i = 0; i< s.length(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j<s.length(); j++)
        {
            if(s.charAt(j)>s.charAt(j+1)){
            char temp = s.charAt(j);
            sb.charAt(j)=sb.charAt(j+1);
            sb.charAt(j+1)=temp;
        }
    }
}}}
```

kindly help me out as i'm a beginner and i cannot figure out why this issue is occurring , thank you .

Comment: sb.charAt(j) is a value, not a variable you can assign.

Comment: `sb.charAt(j)` is a getter. Perhaps you mean `sb.setCharAt(j, ...);`

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a homework assignment where the goal is to sort the characters of a text being entered, so if you enter `gfedbca` the result should be `abcdefg`.

You already got a comment telling you what the problem is: `StringBuffer#charAt()` is not returning a reference to StringBuffer's internal array that you can change the value of. Dependent on the actual assignment you can call StringBuffers `setCharAt` method or you can go another approach by converting the text to sort to a char array and do the sorting in there. There are actually helper-classes in the JVM, that do that for you, have a look e.g. at the [class `java.util.Arrays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

Answer (score 1):

As already answered by many, the issue is in `charAt(index)` you are using, as this returns the character at the given index rather than setting a char at the index position.
My answer is to divert your approach of sorting. For simpler solutions, where  smaller data sets (like your problem) are used, you should use the predefined sorting algorithms, like **Insertion Sort**
You may get help for the algo from here: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/insertion-sort/

Answer (score 0):

StringBuffer's `charAt` returns just the value of the `char` at the index, if you want to swap two chars you need to use setter for that, so you possible want to do somtehing like:

```
for(int j = 0; j < s.length() - 1; j++) {
    if(s.charAt(j) > s.charAt(j + 1)) {
        char temp = s.charAt(j);
        sb.setCharAt(j, sb.charAt(j + 1));
        sb.setCharAt(j + 1, temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this fixes OP's immediate problem, this would still fail because "j + 1" would exceed the max length of the `StringBuffer` instance `sb`.  Please consider adding that to your answer.

Comment: ok, added, but imho this was not actually related to the initial question

Comment: You're right, but this is to avoid OP thinking your solution was ineffective because it still crashes.  To a layman, it would be easy to assume you've not made any progress towards resolving the problem.  Also it is an opportunity to teach someone who needs to learn.

Answer (score 0):

This method can **only return values** and can **not set values**, I guess you might want to use this method:

```
setCharAt()
```

It can meet your requirement